# Save child class in queue of parent shared_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, queue

Imagine the following code:

```
class Request_manager{
public:
    virtual ~Request_manager();
protected:
    explicit Request_manager(type0 start_time);
}

class Ticket : Request_manager{
public:
    Ticket(type1 rq, type2* dataserver,
           type3 tix, type4 start_time);
}

class Card : Request_manager{
public:
    Card(type5 xd, type6* people,
           type7 tr, type8 play_time);
}
```

Now, I have a queue where I want to save `Ticket` and `Card`. For that I create a class called `Tickets_Queue`

```
class Tickets_Queue{
public:
        void push(std::shared_ptr<Request_manager> ticket);
}
```

When I instantiated from somewhere in the code (depending on the script I may be dealing with `Card` or `Ticket`):

```
Tickets_Queue ticket_queue;
auto ticket = std::make_shared<Request_manager>(...,..., ..., ...);
ticket_queue_->push(ticket);
```

I get something like:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:635:39:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = dataserver::Request_manager; _Args = {dataserver::pointdata::Batch_request, dataserver::Data_interface*&, xxxxx::service::Service_ticket&, dataserver::System_time&}]’
data_interfaces/pointdata/Interface.cpp:48:72:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘dataserver::Request_manager(dataserver::pointdata::Batch_request, dataserver::Data_interface*&, ubimet::service::Service_ticket&, dataserver::System_time&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from data_interfaces/Tickets_Queue.h:5:0,
                 from data_interfaces/pointdata/Interface.h:7,
                 from data_interfaces/pointdata/Interface.cpp:1:
data_interfaces/Request_manager.h:30:18: note: candidate: dataserver::Request_manager(dataserver::System_time)
         explicit Ticket(System_time start_time);
                  ^
data_interfaces/Request_manager.h:30:18: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
data_interfaces/Request_manager.h:24:11: note: candidate: constexpr dataserver::Request_manager::Request_manager(const Request_manager&)
     class Ticket {
           ^
data_interfaces/Request_manager.h:24:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
```

On the other hand, if I do:

```
auto ticket = std::make_shared<Ticket>(...,...,...,...);
ticket_queue_->push(ticket);
```

It tells me:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::shared_ptr<Ticket>" to "std::shared_ptr<Request_manager>" exists
```

Which is strange because `Ticket` is a child of `Request_manager` so it should be able to be casted.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of the relevant code then

```
auto ticket = std::make_shared<Request_manager>(...,..., ..., ...);
```

can't possibly work: Request_manager has no constructor taking four arguments.

You *can* have a queue of polymorphic shared_ptrs; however, when you create a queue item you need to make a shared pointer to one of the derived types and put that in the queue, e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<Request_manager> ticket = std::make_shared<Ticket>(...,..., ..., ...);
```

in the above. For the above to work, Ticket and Card must inherit from Request_manager publicly. As below

```
class Ticket : public Request_manager{
public:
    Ticket(type1 rq, type2* dataserver,
           type3 tix, type4 start_time);
}

class Card : public Request_manager{
public:
    Card(type5 xd, type6* people,
           type7 tr, type8 play_time);
}

...

std::shared_ptr<Request_manager> ticket = std::make_shared<Ticket>(...,..., ..., ...);
```

Comment: Doing your statement returns:
`no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::shared_ptr<dataserver::pointdata::Ticket>" to "std::shared_ptr<dataserver::Request_manager>" exists`